# Installing Rails 5.1.5 with Ruby 2.4.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, apple-m1

Firstly, apologies for any inconsistencies: this is my first experience with Ruby and RoR.

I've been trying to install Rails for Ruby 2.4.5.

**I am **required** to stick to Ruby 2.4.5**, and I am given a Gemfile.lock file with a dependency on Rails 5.1.5.

Also i'm using rbenv for version management.

When trying the following:
`gem install rails -v 5.1.5`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    racc requires Ruby version >= 2.5.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)).

I am running a MacBook with an M1 Pro chip. This had created a few complications while installing Ruby, so I suspect this might be a potential reason?

I tried installing different versions of Rails, although this goes against the gemfile, but to no avail.

I tried to install the gemfile directly through Bundler, thinking maybe that'd install Rails,
but got the following:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.5
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.2
Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20231026-14985-19u934u.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.3.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.7.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.7.tar.gz into tmp/arm-apple-darwin23.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.7... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.7... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.7... ERROR, review
'/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/arm-apple-darwin23.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.7/compile.log' to see
what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    int writtentot = 0;
        ^
encoding.c:2569:9: warning: variable 'output' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int output = 0;
        ^
7 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1357:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:402:in `block in execute': Failed to
complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:373:in `chdir'
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:373:in `execute'
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:115:in `compile'
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:154:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:551:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/-darwin-23/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/-darwin-23/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri
```

**Edit:**
Running `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` outputted the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20231026-11138-5eq46d.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.3.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.7.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.7.tar.gz into tmp/arm-apple-darwin23.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.7... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.7... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.7... ERROR, review '/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/arm-apple-darwin23.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.7/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    int writtentot = 0;
        ^
encoding.c:2569:9: warning: variable 'output' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int output = 0;
        ^
7 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1357:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:402:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:373:in `chdir'
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:373:in `execute'
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:115:in `compile'
    from /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.3.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:154:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:551:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/-darwin-23/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/-darwin-23/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Ok, first of all. Since you got a Gemfile to work with it makes no sense to try and install rails using `gem install`. What happens when you try to run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2`? You are missing some binary requirement for sure. Please run it and update your question with a FULL log, or try searching. This is a common problem since forever.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Hey Mike. Thanks for reaching out! Apologies, I'm new to asking questions and new to the whole framework. Please understand that I’ve included what I thought is relevant from the logs for brevity purposes. I've searched thoroughly for this specific issue but couldn't find relevant answers. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: It is quite likely that you will not be able to get the old ruby version to run on an M1 Mac. It might be easier to install it in Docker container.

Comment: Hey, no worries, just trying to fit everything into a comment ;) dbugger makes a great point, you may have better luck trying with Docker, especially if you find an (official) image for Ruby 2.4.5

Comment: The specific problem in your log is `use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'` and honestly I'd do anything rather than try to get to the bottom of how to fix it. It's probably a problem somewhere on the cross-section of old version, changes in default compiles in MacOS and maybe a missing dependency (although I can't find anything about that in the log)

Comment: @dbugger Noted. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Haha okay :). Yeah, I've wasted enough time trying to get to the bottom of it. I'll consider your suggestions, thanks again for taking the time to review the logs Mike!